# Possible insecure login

Tags: javascript, security, passwords, plaintext

At my apartment, I connect to a private WiFi network managed by the building. In order to connect to the internet, I need to sign in via the web-page served by the intranet server.

Out of interest of the fact that my browser does not ask me to save my username and password, I decided to view the source to see how its done. Upon doing so, I bumped into some strange JS code that compiles the password with what appears to be salt and then converts it to `hexMD5`:

```
password = hexMD5(
    '\360' +
     document.login.password.value +
    '\123\076\310\204\336\276\065\360\375\311\365\076\031\311\360\117'
)
```

If the password is being salted and hashed like that, surely the same would need done on the server, which would mean that my password is being saved in plain text? I could be wrong with this, but I'm not seeing any other way.

Any insight into this would be most appreciated, and please let me know if this question is more suites to another SE site.

Comment: I'd have said this question would be more appropriately placed on http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @George, thanks - should I delete this one and move it their, or would it be better if a moderator moved it?

Comment: Uhm… isn't it more likely that the server is storing the hashed version of the password, instead of storing the plaintext version and hashing it during each login attempt? Regardless though, we don't know what the server does or doesn't do or how (in)secure it is.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming hexMD5() is an implementation to convert any string into a MD5 hash. If this is true, then no your password isn't saved in plain text.

The backend could save the MD5 hash and compare the stored hash to the hash it's receiving from login.

But if they create a new salt every time at **login** then yes they might be saving your password as plaintext, unless their implementation is something similar to `md5(salt + md5(password))`.

Security on SO has a lot of threads about hashing, if you want more info.

Comment: The issue is that the salt surrounding the password changes on reload, and it's all being hashed together.

Comment: @MikeRockett If the salt is sent together with the MD5 hash, this isn't a problem. They would just store the salt as well. And even if it's not being sent, it could be stored in session.

Comment: So how would the server get to the same hash without knowing my password, considering that it is all hashed together? If the password was hashed separately, it would make sense to me...

Comment: Oh you're absolutely right, I wasn't paying attention to the fact that this is happening at login. If it's making a new salt at every **login** then everything changes: yes, they would have to store your password as plaintext unless their implementation is some kind of `md5(salt + md5(password))` or similar. I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you for that - I will raise this with the service provider to see if this can be changed.